# Retorno de função jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Olá, estou apanhando em uma coisa muito simples. Tenho uma função em jQuery que verifica se existe algum modal aberto na página. Para isso ele verifica a `class` do `<body>` e retorna 1 se tiver modal aberto e 0 caso não tenha.

Até ai tudo certo. Se eu der um console.log dentro dos `ifs` funciona normalmente. Mas, agora é que vem o "problema".

Tentei de varias formas usar o retorno no meu script `php` mas não consigo. Só quero pegar o retorno, e verificar se é igual a 1, se for tem modal aberto, se for 0 não tem.

Poderiam me ajudar?

função:

```
function verifyModals(){
if ($("body").hasClass("modal-open")) {
    console.log('modal aberto');
    return 1;
}else{
    console.log('modal FECHADO');
    return 0;
}
```

}

No meu script `php`, como vou pegar o retorno? um `echo "<script>verifyModals();</script>";` já não resolveria?

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Você quer recuperar o resultado da função no PHP? seria isso? Fora isso a função já funciona certo?

Comment: sim a função funciona. ela faz o if corretamente. o console.log retorna o esperado. o return nao deveria ser o retorno da função

Comment: Mas você quer pegar esse retorno para usar em um if por exemplo?

Comment: Bom, se não estou enganado, tem uma incompatibilidade de tempo. Tecnicamente você esta chamando a função verifyModals(); antes dessa função existir na página. Então quando a chamada acontece ele não encontra.

Comment: sim eh pra fazer u m if. a pagina php que tem o if  tem no começo um include('funcoes.php); dentro do funcoes php esta esse essa função

Comment: Não vai conseguir fazer dessa forma, pela ordem dos arquivos. O php é carregado no server, então quando tenta carregar usando echo "<script>verifyModals();</script>";. Esse script ainda não existe, ele só passa a existir depois que é enviado ao navegador. Para manipular dessa forma teria que fazer uma chamada direta a algum arquivo php, por meio de ajax, e teria que chamar essa função na sua página diretamente.

Comment: mas como que na primeira execução ele ja da o resultado certo no console?

Comment: outra coisa. a propria funçao jQuery eh quem verifica se tem modal aberto ou nao. como eu vou chamar ela no ajax? vou ter que ter outro arquivo soh pra verificar?

Comment: A função funciona porque seu echo chama ela. Você só não consegue pegar o retorno dela no PHP e usar em um if por exemplo. O echo apenas imprime o que no caso é a tag <script>. E você não chama ela no ajax, se você realmente quer passar esse valor pra trabalhar no PHP, em vez de dar o return, vc utiliza um post de ajax por exemplo. Só uma pergunta, qual o intuito de verificar se existe modal aberto? pode haver outra forma de fazer..

Comment: o intuito eh o seguinte. tenho uma pagina php que verifica algumas coisas no banco. se a informação nao existe, ele abre um modal pra cadastrar. depois recarrega a pagina e verifica novamente. isso N vezes, até todas as informações estiverem cadastradas. no final quando nao tem mais nada pra cadastrar, nao existe nenhum modal. entao eu faria um if perguntando se tem modal aberto, se nao tiver acabou o processo e pode redirecionar pra outra pagina.

Comment: e se dentro do if/else eu fazer um **document.write(0);** e **document.write(1);** ai vai imprimir um retorno certo ? nao daria pra usar?

Comment: esse if no php if(verifyModals() == 1){ echo "modal aberto"; } nao deveria funcionar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41265/discussion-between-fleuquer-lima-and-lipearu).

Comment: o @fleuquer-lima me ajudou no chat. Obrigado

Comment: @FleuquerLima acha que poderia formalizar uma resposta? Pois se deixar no chat fica menos acessível a quem tiver o mesmo problema e chegar aqui no tópico em busca de solução.

Comment: Ok, vou formalizar uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Lipearu,

se eu bem entendi, você quer pegar o retorno dessa sua função jQuery e utilizar no seu script PHP.

Porém isso não é possível, de maneira bem simplória o que acontece é:

1. O usuário faz uma requisição para a sua página
2. O seu servidor recebe a requisição interpreta qual é a página deve ser retornada.
3. O seu código PHP daquela página vai ser interpretado e retornará a página HTML.
4. O servidor pega aquela página e retorna para o usuário.
5. A partir desse momento o seu jQuery começa a funcionar e o seu daquela página não será executado novamente.

O ponto é PHP é interpretado pelo servidor, o jQuery é interpretado pelo navegador. Então se você quer fazer com que o seu retorno seja interpretado por algum PHP, você deverá efetuar uma requisição e obter o seu retorno. Aconselho que você utilize Ajax para tal.

Comment: entao dentro da função jQuery eu nao poderia atribuir um valor a alguma variavel e no php chamar essa variavel ? se eu dou um echo "<script>verifyModals();</script>"; eu estou chamando a função certo ?